# Erro ao localizar XPath

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde, estou com dificuldade para resolver esse problema com selenium, no qual o codigo esta rodando a automação perfeitamente e quando chega em um determinado elemento da página que não contém NAME nem ID, pois se trata de uma lista inserida eu estou usando por XPath.

```
      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
      IWebElement box = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Account_body\"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/a"));
      box.Click();
```

da o seguinte erro no VS:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#Account_body > table > tbody > tr.dataRow.even.first > th > a"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)'
```

.eu não sei se tenho que fazer um Attach como estou acostumado com WinAtomation.

Comment: você gostaria que ele ignorasse caso não exista o elemento, é isso?

Comment: Não pois o elemento existe mesmo, e toda vez que busco por XPath é o mesmo valor

Comment: duas possibilidades então, o elemento não carregou ainda após o wait de cinco segundos ou seu xpath está errado

Comment: nisso que eu fico na merda.. que eu ja coloquei um wait de 20s pra teste e ja conferi XPath, ja me disseram que eu deveria recarregar a pagina como um attach para buscar a referencia. pois n sei se isso seja necessário no selenium

Comment: passa a página ai pra eu dar uma olhada

Comment: eu posso te passar as informações junto com codigo dos elementos e da pg com imagens.. pois é um sistema da credicard para cancelamento de OS

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94561/discussion-between-lucas-miranda-and-igor-fortaleza).